# Change of date format using jQuery works fine with Firefox and Chrome but doesn't work with Safari?

Tags: jquery

The date output is displayed in Firefox and chrome but the date output doesn't display in Safari. What is the problem with the jQuery? Can anyone spot the mistake in it?

```
$datecheck=$('#datedtls').val();
//$datecheck=2011/11/09
var d = new Date($datecheck);
$datecheck=d.format("dd/mm/yyyy");
$("[name=DateRcpt]").val($datecheck);
// output =09/11/2011
```

This is the error I get in Safari,

> SyntaxError: invalid date (undefined,0)

Answer (score 0):

`.format` is not a method of Date, read the documentation,

[Date: Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

If you have a formatting plugin or something from jQuery, use that, like `$.format(d, "....")`

Each browser can have non-standard things it implements. But if it's not a method of the date specification, don't use it.

Comment: dateFormat(d, "dd/mm/yyyy"); tried with this too...getting the same error

Comment: read the docs, that's not a method of Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.  If you have a formatting plugin or something from jQuery, use that, like $.format(d, "....")

Comment: but works fine with firefox and chrome???

Comment: each browser can have non-standard things it implements.  But if it's not a method of the date spec, don't use it.

Comment: Ok, so that's what's wrong... can you also provide him with an actual solution to the problem?